# Base URL for CodeIgniter installation

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp-server, base-url

I have an FTP server (abc.xyz.com), and I want to install CodeIgniter in the ftp server. I followed the instructions at, [CodeIgniter Installation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html) for installing it.

I used FileZilla to copy CI to the root directory of the ftp server. But In Step 3) “set your base URL”, I tried giving the URL of the ftp server. But it does not work. How should I give the base URL. As am new to PHP/CodeIgniter I am not sure how it should be given.

I checked the routes.php and the default controller, welcome.php. It looks fine. But I am not getting the, “Welcome to CodeIgniter” message. Also I checked the same using XAMPP in my local host and it works fine. i.e. After copying CI to 'htdocs', I am able to see CI's Welcome message.

How can I check if CodeIgniter is installed successfully on the ftp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How should I give the base URL?

Try leaving it blank. Codeigiter will do it's best to automatically "guess" the base url, based on some `$_SERVER` variables.

The CI documentation looks like it needs to be updated, this feature [was added in version 2.0.0](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/changelog.html).

Comment: even if I leave it blank, am not getting the welcome message from CI. could you please confirm how I should access my ftp server to see the welcome message.? Is it ftp://abc.xyz.com which should give the welcome message.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell us the actual folder structure your files are in. Is it root > applications, system, blah blah blah or is it root > CodeIgniter > applications, system blah blah blah.

I only ask because I made the same mistake once where I copied the entire work folder "CodeIgniter" from my htdocs folder into my root. You have to copy whats inside that folder and put it in the root.

Comment: It is root -> applications -> config -> config.php. I copied the contents of CI to my root directory. Yeah I have copied only folders inside. could you please confirm how I should access my ftp server to see the welcome message.? Is it ftp://abc.xyz.com which should give the welcome message.